# 500 error editing and updating multiple file uploads rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, multiple-file-upload

I'm using Paperclip and I've added multiple file uploads to one of my models. Everything works fine except when I try to add new files to the existing ones already uploaded. It throws this error:

```
Unexpected error while processing request: expected Hash (got Array) for param `assets_attributes'
```

How can I fix this so that I can add new files? Thanks in advance.

**asset.rb**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :listing

  attr_accessible :asset

  has_attached_file :asset, styles: { large: "700x700>", thumb: "100x100#" }

  validates_attachment_size :asset, :less_than_or_equal_to=>10.megabyte
  validates_attachment_content_type :asset, :content_type=>['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']

end
```

**listing.rb**

```
has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true

attr_accessible :assets_attributes
```

**listings/_edit_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@listing, :html => { class: 'form-horizontal ', :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <% if @listing.errors.any? %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div>
        <%= file_field_tag('listing_assets_asset', multiple: true, name: "listing[assets_attributes][][asset]", id: 'file-upload3', class: '') %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

**listings_controller.rb**

```
  before_filter :authenticate_member!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] 
  before_filter :find_member
  before_filter :find_listing, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @listing = Listing.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @listing }
    end
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = current_member.listings.new(params[:listing])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        current_member.create_activity(@listing, 'created')
        format.html { redirect_to @listing }
        format.json { render json: @listing, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /listings/1
  # PUT /listings/1.json
  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update_attributes(params[:listing])
        format.html { redirect_to @listing }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def find_member
      @member = Member.find_by_user_name(params[:user_name])
    end 

    def find_listing
      @listing = current_member.listings.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Comment: Can you post the request output from your server console? You might also check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577631/rails-form-with-multiple-nested-models-causes-issues-with-radio-groups

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That fixed the error issue but did not fix my overall problem. I found the fix to my problem by looking at this article: http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/

I needed to change the way I was handling multiple uploads.

Changing my input to this:

```
<%= file_field_tag "assets[]", type: :file, multiple: true, id: 'file-upload3' %>
```

and adding the following to my create and update actions in my controler:

```
if params[:assets]
    params[:assets].each { |asset|
      @listing.assets.create(asset: asset)
    }
end
```

Doing these things resolved my issue.

Comment: This is a poor approach, adding this hack into your controller instead of pursuing doing it properly using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` where you had begun.

Answer (score 1):

The `accepts_nested_attributes_for` expects a hash for the `*_attributes` value that it processes, the hash it expects has the array indices as the keys, ie. it expects something like this:

```
asset_attributes: {
  0 => { asset: value_for_0 },
  1 => { asset: value_for_1 }
}
```

By creating the name of your form field as `listing[assets_attributes][][asset]` you're actually creating an array, ie.

```
asset_attributes: [
  { asset: value_for_0 },
  { asset: value_for_1 }
]
```

This is why you've received the error.

I think what you meant to name your field was: `listing[assets_attributes][asset][]` which would create:

```
asset_attributes: {
  0 => { asset: [ array, of, IO, objects, for, your, files ] }
}
```

Comment: That fixes the 500 error but then I get this: `can't convert String into Integer` `app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:86:in 'block in update'` `app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:85:in `update'`

Comment: I'm glad to hear that my answer resolved the problem you posted (hint hint :)  You're new to StackOverflow, so first of all welcome, and then please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Then, after trying a few things to resolve your new problem you can post a new question with the details of it.